# MySQL Data too long for column 'XX' at row 'XX' - LongBlob Column

Tags: c#, mysql, file, blob, long-integer

I have a C# (VS2010) windows application which calls a MySQL(Version 5.6.17) database. In database I am storing files. I have defined column LONGBLOB to store files.

When I try to insert data to my table I'm getting the error "Data too long for column 'XX' at row 'XX'". I found that by increasing  max_allowed_packet this problem can be solved. But I still get the same error after increasing value of  max_allowed_packet.

I cannot even insert a 70 KB file. I can only insert only small files as 20-30KB

I cannot save files in a hard drive and store only path in the database due to some restrictions. So I cannot store path in database.

Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: Is the hard drive full?

Comment: What did you change `max_allowed_packet` to?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to increase size of column data type to some higher values. Increasing max_allowed_packet will only help when you are importing data from a sql dump in your database.

Good Luck